# Display weekdays using ifelse

Tags: java, if-statement, calendar

I am writing this code to display weekdays by calling it from the main function using if else statement but I can't display the days after Monday. It seems like rest of the if-else statement is not being called. Please help..

```
public class WeekdayName {

    public static String weekday_name(int weekday) {
        String result = "";

        if ( weekday == 1 ) {
            result = "Sunday";
        } else if ( weekday == 2 ) {
            result = "Monday";
        } else if ( weekday == 3 ) {
            result = "Tuesday";
        } else if ( weekday == 4 ) {
            result = "Wednesday";
        } else if ( weekday == 5 ) {
            result = "Thursday";
        } else if ( weekday == 6 ) {
            result = "Friday";
        } else if ( weekday == 7 ) {
            result = "Saturday";
        } else if ( weekday == 0 ) {
            result = "Sunday";
        } else {
            result = "ERROR";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        System.out.println( "Weekday 1: " + weekday_name(1) );
        System.out.println( "Weekday 2: " + weekday_name(2) );
        System.out.println( "Weekday 3: " + weekday_name(3) );
        System.out.println( "Weekday 4: " + weekday_name(4) );
        System.out.println( "Weekday 5: " + weekday_name(5) );
        System.out.println( "Weekday 6: " + weekday_name(6) );
        System.out.println( "Weekday 7: " + weekday_name(7) );
        System.out.println( "Weekday 0: " + weekday_name(0) );
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println( "Weekday 43: " + weekday_name(43) );
        System.out.println( "Weekday 17: " + weekday_name(17) );
        System.out.println( "Weekday -1: " + weekday_name(-1) );

        Calender calender = new GregorianCalender();
        int dayofWeek = calender.get(Calender.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        System.out.println( "\nToday is a " + weekday_name(dayofWeek) + "!" );
    }

}
```

please help guys...

Comment: It's `Calendar`, not `Calender`.

Comment: Care to include the program output and explain why you think it's incorrect?

Comment: Once you make the code compile, by correctly spelling Calend**a**r, it works fine. See [Ideone](https://ideone.com/eJZc69).

Comment: I am new to java as well as this site, and I don't understand the reason behind putting this question 'ON HOLD'. What do i do to reopen it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code does not compile due to two problems:

- It's `Calendar`, not `Calender`
- You need to import `java.util.Calendar` as well

The reason why you are only seeing output for Monday might be that you are unknowingly executing an older (correctly compiled) version of your source that did not yet include outputs for the other days. But that's just speculation.

Note that `DAY_OF_WEEK` does not actually return `0`, so you might consider returning `ERROR` for that case as well.

Fixed code:

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class WeekdayName {
    public static String weekday_name(int weekday) {
        String result = "";

        if (weekday == 1) {
            result = "Sunday";
        } else if (weekday == 2) {
            result = "Monday";
        } else if (weekday == 3) {
            result = "Tuesday";
        } else if (weekday == 4) {
            result = "Wednesday";
        } else if (weekday == 5) {
            result = "Thursday";
        } else if (weekday == 6) {
            result = "Friday";
        } else if (weekday == 7) {
            result = "Saturday";
        } else if (weekday == 0) {
            result = "Sunday";
        } else {
            result = "ERROR";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Weekday 1: " + weekday_name(1));
        System.out.println("Weekday 2: " + weekday_name(2));
        System.out.println("Weekday 3: " + weekday_name(3));
        System.out.println("Weekday 4: " + weekday_name(4));
        System.out.println("Weekday 5: " + weekday_name(5));
        System.out.println("Weekday 6: " + weekday_name(6));
        System.out.println("Weekday 7: " + weekday_name(7));
        System.out.println("Weekday 0: " + weekday_name(0));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Weekday 43: " + weekday_name(43));
        System.out.println("Weekday 17: " + weekday_name(17));
        System.out.println("Weekday -1: " + weekday_name(-1));

        Calendar calender = new GregorianCalendar();
        int dayofWeek = calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        System.out.println("\nToday is a " + weekday_name(dayofWeek) + "!");
    }
}
```

Afterwards, your logic appears to be working fine:

```
Weekday 1: Sunday
Weekday 2: Monday
Weekday 3: Tuesday
Weekday 4: Wednesday
Weekday 5: Thursday
Weekday 6: Friday
Weekday 7: Saturday
Weekday 0: Sunday

Weekday 43: ERROR
Weekday 17: ERROR
Weekday -1: ERROR

Today is a Saturday!
```

Comment: yes i was executing an older (correctly compiled) source code and thus it didn't work after monday, even after correcting the TYPO and using the import java.util.Calendar. So i copied it into a new file and it worked. Thanks for your great answer.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You have got a typo there. It's `Calendar` not `Calender`.

**2.** The output is:

```
Weekday 1: Sunday
Weekday 2: Monday
Weekday 3: Tuesday
Weekday 4: Wednesday
Weekday 5: Thursday
Weekday 6: Friday
Weekday 7: Saturday
Weekday 0: Sunday

Weekday 43: ERROR
Weekday 17: ERROR
Weekday -1: ERROR

Today is a Saturday!
```

So it seems it works for me.

**3.** You'd better use a switch statement. It's shorter and elegant, look:

```
public static String weekday_name( int weekday )
{
    switch (weekday) {
        case 1: return "Sunday";
        case 2: return "Monday";
        case 3: return "Tuesday";
        case 4: return "Wednesday";
        case 5: return "Thursday";
        case 6: return "Friday";
        case 7: return "Saturday";
        case 0: return "Sunday";
        default: return "ERROR";
    }
}
```

The output is same as well :)

Answer (score 0):

> Your mistake is just the spelling `GregorianCalender` it
>   should be `GregorianCalendar` and  `Calender` should be
>   `Calendar`.
>
> And you need to `import java.util.Calendar;` in your code.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

    public class WeekdayNAme
    {
        public static String weekday_name( int weekday )
        {
            String result = "";

            if ( weekday == 1 )
            {
                result = "Sunday";
            }
            else if ( weekday == 2 )
            {
                result = "Monday";
            }
            else if ( weekday == 3 )
            {
                result = "Tuesday";
            }
            else if ( weekday == 4 )
            {
                result = "Wednesday";
            }

            else if ( weekday == 5 )
            {
                result = "Thursday";
            }
            else if ( weekday == 6 )
            {
                result = "Friday";
            }

            else if ( weekday == 7 )
            {
                result = "Saturday";
            }
            else if ( weekday == 0 )
            {
                result = "Sunday";
            }
            else
            {
                result = "ERROR";
            }
            return result;
        }


        public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            System.out.println( "Weekday 1: " + weekday_name(1) );
            System.out.println( "Weekday 2: " + weekday_name(2) );
            System.out.println( "Weekday 3: " + weekday_name(3) );
            System.out.println( "Weekday 4: " + weekday_name(4) );
            System.out.println( "Weekday 5: " + weekday_name(5) );
            System.out.println( "Weekday 6: " + weekday_name(6) );
            System.out.println( "Weekday 7: " + weekday_name(7) );
            System.out.println( "Weekday 0: " + weekday_name(0) );
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println( "Weekday 43: " + weekday_name(43) );
            System.out.println( "Weekday 17: " + weekday_name(17) );
            System.out.println( "Weekday -1: " + weekday_name(-1) );

            Calendar calender = new GregorianCalendar();
            int dayofWeek = calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

            System.out.println( "\nToday is a " + weekday_name(dayofWeek) + "!" );
        }

    }
```

> after that it will produce the flowing output:

```
Weekday 1: Sunday
Weekday 2: Monday
Weekday 3: Tuesday
Weekday 4: Wednesday
Weekday 5: Thursday
Weekday 6: Friday
Weekday 7: Saturday
Weekday 0: Sunday

Weekday 43: ERROR
Weekday 17: ERROR
Weekday -1: ERROR

Today is a Saturday!
```

Answer (score 0):

Youhave a typo with the class

```
Calender calender = new GregorianCalender();
int dayofWeek = calender.get(Calender.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

must be

```
Calendar calender = new GregorianCalendar();
int dayofWeek = calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% related, but an enum gives an elegant solution here...

```
private enum WeekDay {
    SUNDAY,
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAY;

    static WeekDay fromDayNumber(int dayNumber) {
        return WeekDay.values()[dayNumber -1];
    }
}
```

...
       Calendar calender = new GregorianCalendar();
        int dayofWeek = calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

```
    System.out.println( "\nToday is a " + WeekDay.fromDayNumber(dayofWeek) + "!" );
```

...